# Try-Catch with Yield return in a Recursive Method

Tags: c#, methods, try-catch, ienumerable, yield-return

I need to implement a try catch in a recursive method, but i can't figure out how to do it. This is the code:

```
    private IEnumerable <FileItem> FilesToDownload(FileItem file)
    {
        logger = LogManager.GetLogger(GetType());

        using (var wb = new WebDavSession(webDavUrl, new NetworkCredential(user, psw)))
        using (Task<IList<WebDavSessionItem>> task = wb.ListAsync(file.Path))
        {
            task.Wait();
            foreach (var item in task.Result)
            {
                FileItem retFile = item.ToFileItem();
                logger.Info("Going Into " + retFile.Path);
                if (item.IsFolder == true)  
                {
                    foreach (var inner in FilesToDownload(retFile))
                    {
                        yield return inner;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    yield return retFile;
                }
            }
        } 
    }
```

This method helps me to find out files into nested folders (in a cloud), so the recursive is necessary.

Whay do you suggest?

Comment: Suggest for what? Do you have any specific problem here? Some compiler-error for instance?

Comment: I think the more pressing issue is that you've called `task.Wait();` - you might get away with that in some contexts, but that is absolutely **not** how you're meant to use async methods. Unfortunately, there's no pre-existing pattern for "async enumerables" - it has been discussed many times but not properly concluded yet

Comment: I don't see a `try...catch`...

Comment: what happens when you add try/catch? Note: the compiler has evolved in this area over the years, so it is also relevant to ask: what compiler version (or what IDE version, if it is easier) are you using?

Comment: Yes, Try Catch with Yields return doesn't work. @HimBromBeere

Comment: @MNeg oh it does, but it depends where you put them!

Comment: @MarcGravell Yes, i saw that already on other questions, and they find out a "partial solution" but not in this particular case.  Anyways, I can't even compile, on the yield, says : "Cannot yield a value in the body of a try with a catch cause".

Comment: Then please add your *actual* code, in particular where the try/catch is involved. From your current code it´s impossible to guess, as we don´t see any try/catch at all.

Comment: @HimBromBeere it is my actual code, i just removed a try catch, c'mon..

Comment: @MarcGravell Anyways, thank you for your code. i'll try it out. Wow that was brilliant!

Comment: When your question is about why you can´t use a try/catch and you don´t show that try/catch, how should we guess why it´s not working as you´ve expected?

Comment: @HimBromBeere I just copied the code i'm using, forgetting the try catch (that was giving me the error) - but as I can see, It wasn't so hard to understand, as Marc promptly answered me .......... Anyways thank you for the time spent on this question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you *can't* do is have a `try`/`catch` block *around* a `yield return` statement - that violates [CS1626](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs1626).

But: you can still use `try`/`catch` - you just need to be creative in the layout. For example:

```
foreach (var item in task.Result)
{
    IEnumerable<FileItem> subItems = null;
    FileItem subItem = null;

    try
    {
        FileItem retFile = item.ToFileItem();
        logger.Info("Going Into " + retFile.Path);
        if (item.IsFolder == true)
        {
            subItems = FilesToDownload(retFile);
        }
        else
        {
            subItem = retFile;
        }
    }
    catch { /* your code here */ }
    if (subItem != null) yield return subItem;
    if (subItems != null)
    {
        foreach (var x in subItems) yield return x;
    }
}
```

Additional thoughts:

- a `Stack<T>` or `Queue<T>` may be a more suitable approach than deep recursion
- the `task.Wait()` is not good and could deadlock your code; unfortunately there is currently no good pattern for "async enumerables"